Gitlab's tag event is not triggering the jenkins multibranch pipeline
My goal is to trigger a multibranch pipeline in jenkins when a tag is created in gitlab.
This is my trigger config in jenkinsfile :
       triggers {
       gitlab(
               triggerOnPush: true,                // Disable trigger on regular branch pushes
               triggerOnMergeRequest: true,       // Disable trigger on merge requests
               triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush: "both", // Disable trigger on open merge requests<
               //triggerOnTagPush: true,             // Enable trigger on tag pushes
               branchFilterType: 'All',            // Trigger on all branches (optional, adjust as needed)
               cancelPendingBuildsOnUpdate: true,   // Cancel pending builds if new push/tag is detected
               triggerOnAcceptedMergeRequest: true,
               triggerOnApprovedMergeRequest: true
       )
   }

And the config in the refspec's project :

ofc, I configured the webhook correctly on the gitlab's end and I activated the push and merge request events.

My Pipeline is launched upon these triggers :

on push
merge request accepted

My Pipeline is NOT launched upon these triggers :

on tag push
on merge request approved
on merge request created (I know that this is only available in gitlab's entreprise edition)

And in jenkins's log, I'm seing the tag event is getting received :
 Push: {
  "object_kind" : "tag_push",
  "event_name" : "tag_push",
  "before" : "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "after" : "a6faedc42b129681e36ead05a3c7c07a3d59d335",
  "ref" : "refs/tags/v3.0",
  "ref_protected" : false,
  ....
 }

Am I missing something ?
Thank you.
